# Use maxlength as a CSS width

Tags: css

I tried to use the `maxlength` attribute of an `input` element as a CSS `width`, but it does not seem to work:

```css
input[maxlength] {
  width: attr(maxlength em);
}
```

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) I thought this might be the intended use case. Yes I saw the note. Is there any other way to get it working?

This works, but scales too much.

```css
input[maxlength="2"] {
  width: 2em;
}

input[maxlength="3"] {
  width: 3em;
}
```

Comment: what could work in the future: `width: calc(attr(maxlength)*1em)` .. in a far future ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `ch` unit instead of `em`. `ch` corresponds to the width of the `0` character, which you can use in combination with a monospaced font to get input fields of width exactly the same as the maximum content you can fit within.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("sample-btn").addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById("nick-input").value = "ShadyMedic_00155"
        document.getElementById("msg-input").value = "Sometimes I wish Stack Overflow wasn't so toxic to new users..."
    })
})
```

```css
input[type=text] {
    font-family: monospace;
}
input[maxlength="16"] {
    width: 16ch;
}
input[maxlength="63"] {
    width: 63ch;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="name-input">Nickname:</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="16" id="nick-input" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="msg-input">Comment:</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="63" id="msg-input" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
  </p>
</form>

<button id="sample-btn">Fill with sample data</button>
```